# Different IDs for the "Usage and Health Data Collection Service Application" managed service

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, service-application

I am working on sharepoint on-premises 2013. and i am trying to get the ID of the "Usage and Health Data Collection Service Application", but i got different IDs:-

1) When i run this powershell i get this ID:-

```
PS C:\Users\spfarm.user> Get-SPServiceApplication -Name  WSS_UsageApplication

DisplayName          TypeName             Id
-----------          --------             --
WSS_UsageApplication Usage and Health ... 80ace510-005c-4786-86fc-bfd3848e2d79
```

While using this powershell i got this ID:-

```
PS C:\Users\spfarm.user> Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy

    DisplayName          TypeName             Id
    -----------          --------             --
    WSS_UsageApplication Usage and Health ... 21c44849-db6e-4be8-9d2e-84755dcc664a
```

so which IDs i should trust? or i have an issue inside our farm?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID which gets from Get-SPServiceApplication command is the ID of the "Usage and Health Data Collection Service Application".

The second ID is the ID of Usage and Health Data Collection proxy. This is the proxy that virtualizes the access to the service application.

Comment: ok i see. now if i want to provision this service using this power-shell script `$UP = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | where {$_.ID -eq "<PASTE COPIED ID HERE>"}
$UP.Provision()` then which ID i need to use?

Comment: Use the second ID which gets from Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy command.